# Adding characters within strings in an R dataframe column

Tags: r, date

This is the first line of my dataframe (with column names):

```
site, date, value
TEES, 20000314, 315
```

As you can see, the dates don't have separators (- or /), so I can't use `as.Date`. Thus, I need something like this:

```
TEES, 2000-03-14, 315
```

How do I do this? Presumably something with `sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work:

```
as.Date(gsub('(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})','\\1-\\2-\\3',df$date))
[1] "2000-03-14"
```

Data:

```
df
  site     date value
1 TEES 20000314   315
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ymd` function from the `lubridate` package. This will automatically add "-" to separate YYYY-MM-DD and convert it to `Date`.

```
library(lubridate)

ymd(df$date)

# "2000-03-14"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as.Date` you just need to specify the `tryFormats` argument:

```
as.Date("20000314", tryFormats = c("%Y%m%d"))
[1] "2000-03-14"
```

The default is to try these formats: `c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d")`, which don't match your current structure so you have to tell it how to read your structure.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anydate("20000314")
#[1] "2000-03-14"
```